# Soql from child to parent

Tags: apex, soql

I have custom junction object which has Master-detail relation ship with contact. Generally we have relation ship field that contain contact name in junction object.but I want write soql query to fetch recods from child object where contact owner is 'ram'.

Answer (score 5):

This [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) from the Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference should help.

> When you use a child-to-parent relationship, you can use dot notation:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, FirstName__c, Mother_of_Child__r.FirstName__c
> FROM Daughter__c
> WHERE Mother_of_Child__r.LastName__c LIKE 'C%'
> ```

In your case the `Mother_of_Child__r.LastName__c LIKE 'C%'` would be something like `Contact__r.Owner.Name = 'ram'` the Contact__r depends on the API Name of your relationship field.

Comment: Nice reference.